# Searchkick and Elasticsearch connection issue in rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Im pushing my app to production and having issues with the elasticsearch connection.  When I SSH into my server and try to reindex (or do anything with Elasticsearch) I get the following error:

```
    deploy@living-recipe-server-01:~/living-recipe/current$ bundle exec rails searchkick:reindex CLASS=Recipe --trace
** Invoke searchkick:reindex (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute searchkick:reindex
I, [2020-01-02T14:26:25.952020 #5698]  INFO -- : GET http://10.138.104.120:9200/_alias [status:503, request:30.012s, query:N/A]
D, [2020-01-02T14:26:25.952127 #5698] DEBUG -- : < {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null}],"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null},"status":503}
F, [2020-01-02T14:26:25.952158 #5698] FATAL -- : [503] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null}],"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null},"status":503}
rails aborted!
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::ServiceUnavailable: [503] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null}],"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null},"status":503}
```

I know the connection is good with Elasticsearch cause when I run the curl command to check the port I get the following

```
{
  "name" : "living-recipe-elasticsearch",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.5.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "3ae9ac9a93c95bd0cdc054951cf95d88e1e18d96",
    "build_date" : "2019-12-16T22:57:37.835892Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Ive just got the basic searchkick configuration and everything works fine on my development machine.  Here is my elasticsearch.rb initializer:

```
require "faraday"
require "typhoeus/adapters/faraday"

Searchkick.timeout = 90
Searchkick.client.transport.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200"
```

This has been stumping me and not sure what else to try at this point

EDIT:
So uninstalled and reinstall elasticsearch on my server.  This is a new deployment.  When I look into the logs this is the output:

```
[2020-01-02T16:30:15,935][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [es-node-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/vda1)]], net usable_space [75.1gb], net total_space [77.3gb], types [ext4]
[2020-01-02T16:30:15,947][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [es-node-1] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2020-01-02T16:30:15,962][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] node name [es-node-1], node ID [EO9hHv6uRtGsYw9ZRNLXtg], cluster name [recipes_prodcution]
[2020-01-02T16:30:15,963][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] version[7.5.1], pid[4383], build[default/deb/3ae9ac9a93c95bd0cdc054951cf95d88e1e18d96/2019-12-16T22:57:37.835892Z], OS[Linux/4.15.0-66-generic/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/13.0.$
[2020-01-02T16:30:15,964][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]
[2020-01-02T16:30:15,965][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitS$
[2020-01-02T16:30:19,385][WARN ][o.e.x.w.Watcher          ] [es-node-1] the [action.auto_create_index] setting is configured to be restrictive [.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*].  for the next 6 months daily history indices are allowed to $
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,988][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [flattened]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,989][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [frozen-indices]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,990][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,990][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,991][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,991][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,991][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,991][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,992][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,992][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [parent-join]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,993][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [percolator]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,993][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,993][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [reindex]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,994][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [repository-url]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,994][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [search-business-rules]
[2020-01-02T16:30:21,994][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [spatial]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,010][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [systemd]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,011][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [transform]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,011][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,011][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [vectors]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,012][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-analytics]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,012][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,012][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,013][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,013][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-enrich]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,013][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,014][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,014][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,014][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,015][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,015][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,015][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,015][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,016][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,016][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2020-01-02T16:30:22,017][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-node-1] no plugins loaded
[2020-01-02T16:30:33,879][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [es-node-1] parsed [0] roles from file [/etc/elasticsearch/roles.yml]
[2020-01-02T16:30:35,410][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [es-node-1] [controller/4493] [Main.cc@110] controller (64 bit): Version 7.5.1 (Build ae3c3c51b849be) Copyright (c) 2019 Elasticsearch BV
[2020-01-02T16:30:37,010][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] [es-node-1] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security
[2020-01-02T16:30:37,351][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [es-node-1] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2020-01-02T16:30:40,431][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] initialized
[2020-01-02T16:30:40,432][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] starting ...
[2020-01-02T16:30:40,910][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [es-node-1] publish_address {167.172.112.123:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2020-01-02T16:30:41,376][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [es-node-1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2020-01-02T16:30:51,425][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [es-node-1] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is empty on this node: have discovered [{es-node-1}{EO9hHv$
[2020-01-02T16:31:01,429][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [es-node-1] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is empty on this node: have discovered [{es-node-1}{EO9hHv$
[2020-01-02T16:31:11,439][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [es-node-1] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is empty on this node: have discovered [{es-node-1}{EO9hHv$
[2020-01-02T16:31:11,492][WARN ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] timed out while waiting for initial discovery state - timeout: 30s
[2020-01-02T16:31:11,574][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [es-node-1] publish_address {167.172.112.123:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2020-01-02T16:31:11,575][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-node-1] started
[2020-01-02T16:31:21,442][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [es-node-1] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is empty on this node: have discovered [{es-node-1}{EO9hHv$
```

Comment: it looks like wrong elasticsearch deployment configuration- master node not configured. Did you use this elasticsearch deployment before? can you cURL some basic queries to it? As example index list ‘GET your-up/_cat/master?v’

Comment: Every command i run i get the master_not discovered yet error...other then the simple connection check.  See edits for startup logs

Comment: so in this case I can say that you elasticsearch not properly installed and configured. For test you can try cloud elastic.co or bonsai free cloud solutions. Or follow documentation and tutorials from elastic.co about installation and configuration.

Comment: Well cloud on elastic.co works, so will have to look into fixing my install or use that.  At least for now the 14-day trial will work

Comment: any solution for this issue?